# Creating 32bpp BMP file for toolbar image strip?

Tags: visual-studio, bmp, vsix

I've got a 16 pixel high image that I've created in Paint.NET that I'd like to use in a Visual Studio toolbar.

My image is a .PDN file with multiple layers. Visual Studio requires a 32bpp BMP file. How do I convert the .PDN file to the correct format .BMP file?

I'm not looking to have this happen in my program.

I'm cool with having to do something manually whenever a change is made to the .PDN file, although I'd prefer something I can integrate with my automated build.

I've tried using the BmpX extension to Paint.NET, but it saves the background as white, rather than transparent. I've tried using ImageMagick's convert utility, but something's wrong with the saved BMP file, and VS displays it slightly corrupted and offset to the right by a couple of pixels.

*Note:* I'm using convert.exe by saving from Paint.NET as a .PNG file and then using `convert strip.png strip.bmp`. The transparency's correct, though.

Comment: Just give me these details..
Are you want to use in C# windows application toolbar?
Why not just create a bmp file in Paint.Net and add it in to your application' toolbar?
Are you need transparent image only?

Comment: I need a 24-bit BMP file, because I want the colour depth. I need a 32-bit (RGBA) BMP file, because the Visual Studio Extensibility model doesn't support 24-bit BMP files. This is not for my app; it's for a VS extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that VS2010 [can cope with .PNG files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/15-minute-blog-post-png-files-in-packages/).